# Mesh blacks out as I zoom out

Tags: texturing, materials, 3d-view

I imported this .obj from some site and after applying the provided textures the viewport does this.

Zoomed in on the mesh looks fine, but as I zoom out it gets all black. I think it has something to do with textures since it doesn't happen with non-textured surfaces.

[image]
[image]
[here is the .blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7fkkzfq5qG1RjVCZXBEY3d6NEE)

Comment: Hi. If you want to provide files for us to look at, please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ exclusively. Files on other services tend to "vanish" over time, thus rendering your question and possible answers eventually useless. Thanks.

Comment: that link should've been ther at the ask question page or maybe it was i didn't notice it. will do.

Comment: Someone please answer/..... im waiting desparaeterly

Comment: It's not that nobody wants to answer your question. Normally people answer very quickly but sometimes it's just that nobody knows a good answer to a problem. It might have to do something with the weird UV organization that .obj files tend to have. I'll take a look into it tomorrow, maybe I come up with something...

Comment: should i also link the originial .obj and textures if it might help?

Comment: Someone please solve my problem or should i report a bug?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You just need to change the texture filetype to .png instead of.dds

[image: result image]

Comment: I think this was a little uncalled for, please be a little more considerate of everyone else here. **This is a purely volunteer site**, and many people have real jobs that take the vast majority of their time. I know that at least for myself, after an 8-10 hour day at the computer working I don't always want to go digging through the days questions. Also, it is easy for a question to get buried. I'd recommend hopping onto the site chat in future if your question remains un-answered for a few days. Your answer is extremely unprofessional, and makes a very bad impression on us.